# PDO Update query secure?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to understand and read up on PDO.

I've just written the following and it works fine, but I'm wondering if its secure as I dont escape any variables, is it still a requirement I escape these?

```
// Get Post Variables 
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email_addr = $_POST['email_addr'];
$user_type = $_POST['user_type'];


// query
$sql = "UPDATE users
    SET first_name=?, surname=?, email_addr=?, user_age=?, user_type=?
    WHERE user_id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($first_name,$surname,$email_addr,$user_age,$user_type,$uid));
```

Answer (score 5):

Escaping variables is not needed in a `prepare()` statement, since it's one of the reasons to use those statements, as indicated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() (...) helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.